# ASP .NET MVC 4.5 Style Bundling not outputting anything

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP .NET MVC 4 app with BundleConfig.cs in the App_Start folder and a call to this class and the RegisterBundles method within the Global.asax.

Everything works fine regarding the Script bundling, but the style bundling produces nothing.

```
  var bundle = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css")
                            .Include("~/Themes/Rikkle.Web/Styles/app.min.css");
            BundleTable.Bundles.Add(bundle);
```

I access the above bundle on the page like so:

```
<link href="/bundles/css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I am manually calling the link as opposed to using @Styles.Render() because the page output NOTHING when I call this (again, all script bundling still works). When I go to localhost:xxx/bundles/css in the browser I get a Status Code of 200, everything is fine, just that the payload is nothing. When I go to localhost:/themes/rikkle.web/styles/app.min.css in the browser, it pulls up without an issue.

Also, I am referencing System.Web.Optimization, the latest drop from Nuget, in both my views folder web.config and the main web.config.

Comment: It's due to the file extension of "*.min.css". See if [this technique][1] helps:

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/mvc4-bundler-not-including-min-files

Comment: This is totally correct, and completely answers this issue.

Comment: Stack Overflow didn't like my short answer and automatically moved it to a comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

This question is answered by: [Bundler not including .min files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/mvc4-bundler-not-including-min-files)

Essentially, if you have "min," as in "app.min.css," then the bundling blows up.