# How to prevent usage of *.min.js in BundleTransformer?

Tags: asp.net, bundle

I use **BundleTransformer.Core 1.9.25**. I have included *angular-animate.js* in bundle. But in generated bundle file I saw the error:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(402,118-125): run-time error JS1019: Can't have 'break' outside of loop: break a
```

The reason is that the bundle uses *angular-animate.min.js* instead of *angular-animate.js*. When I delete *angular-animate.min.js* file, it uses *angular-animate.js* and there is not errors.

*Web.config* contains:

```
<bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
  <core>
    <js usePreMinifiedFiles="false">
      <translators>
        <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
      </translators>
      <minifiers>
        <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
      </minifiers>
      <fileExtensions>
        <add fileExtension=".js" assetTypeCode="JavaScript" />
      </fileExtensions>
    </js>
  </core>
</bundleTransformer>
```

As you see `usePreMinifiedFiles=false` attribute doesn't prevent usage of existing **.min.js* files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just forgot to add `ScriptTransformer` in *App_Start/BundleConfig.cs*:

```
var scriptTransformer = new ScriptTransformer();
bundle.Transforms.Add(scriptTransformer);
```

It fixed the problem.

But I chose the solution without using `ScriptTransformer` (BundleTransformer.Core). It is cleaning of `FileExtensionReplacementList` list:

```
bundles.FileExtensionReplacementList.Clear();
```

By default `FileExtensionReplacementList` has two values:

```
.Add("min", OptimizationMode.WhenEnabled);
.Add("debug", OptimizationMode.WhenDisabled);
```

And it was a cause of my problem.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me.  I used `bundles.FileExtensionReplacementList.Clear(); bundles.FileExtensionReplacementList.Add("debug", OptimizationMode.WhenDisabled);`

Comment: doesn't it minify js files on every HTTP request?

Answer (score -1):

In the BundleConfig.cs file find

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

and change the value to false.

Comment: No, I want to concatenate and minify bundle, but I don't want the bundle uses *.min.js files, which are not in the bundle.

Comment: If someone did this to fix a problem, they might as well just not be using bundles.