# Asp.Net MVC4 Bundling & Minification .min.js files excluded from Scripts.Render?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I created some theme HtmlHelper extensions for that grab the .css and .js files in a theme directory and dynamically register them as bundles. However, if the theme only contains .min.js files, the Scripts.Render output is empty in debug mode.

Is there a way to include *.min.js files in the output for Scripts.Render when in debug mode?

Comment: I think this has be files a bug with Optimization...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
BundleTable.Bundles.IgnoreList.Clear(); // apparently, IgnoreList included .min.js in debug
BundleTable.Bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore(".intellisense.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
BundleTable.Bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("-vsdoc.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
BundleTable.Bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore(".debug.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
```

Comment: For a more in-depth explanation, check out [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12901050/230390).

Answer (score 1):

Faced same problem earlier......all i did was to upgrade the asp.net web optimization to the latest alpha version.

Comment: this crashed mine on dev machine had to add this `bundles.DirectoryFilter.Clear();` to BundleConfig.cs fiel to fix dev machine, this however did not fix my live machine yet