# Why are my style bundles not rendering correctly in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am new to ASP.NET MVC 4 (well, I used 3 a little).

Anyway, in my BundleConfig.cs file, I am trying to load the Twitter Bootstrap css files and an additional `site.css` file.

But only the site.css file is rendered.  I have confirmed that the bootstrap css files are indeed in the right place (Content folder) and are in the same location as the site.css

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css",
            "~/Content/site.css"));
```

**EDIT**

OK, this isn't my preferred way but Andrei Drynov recommended I try:

```
@import url("bootstrap.min.css")
body{background: #e8e6da;padding-top:60px;padding-bottom:40px;}
@import url("bootstrap-responsive.min.css")
```

But that doesn't work.  I changed the site.css to the above but now the background body color doesn't even work.  If I remove the @imports the background is the correct color.

**EDIT 2**

I don't get it but adding:

```
bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
```

To my bundles file fixed it.  Hmmm.  Not sure I understand.  But I was able to remove the @imports out of the site.css.

Strange.

Comment: If you look at the Network tab in developer tools, are those CSS files obtained?

Comment: Nope.  I see site.css and some JS that I load.

Comment: How do you reference the bundle in your layout or view?

Comment: I have bundles.IgnoreList.Clear() in RegisterBundles. Interesting, thought it was for ScriptBundles...

Comment: Sorry, missed semicolons after @import. Answer updated.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The default behaviour is for the IgnoreList to ignore any minified scripts.

You can either remove the '.min' from their names, or clear the IgnoreList.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Bundles will automatically use the minified version, so don't include that in the script name, just use `bootstrap.css` instead, and keep the un-minified version in your content directory.

Answer (score 15):

Just to let anybody else know who cant find a working solution easily in this long thread, I had the exact same issue and i solved it in the same way as suggested in edits found at the bottom of the actual question!

I started a new project MVC4 Web Application, created routes for bootstrap bundles in the exact same code shown above:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css",
            "~/Content/site.css"));
```

But due to unknown reasons, it was not loading.. Finally i gave up and decided to google it and found this page.

I tried adding the following as the first line in BundleConfig.cs file. Recompiled and everything started working and now the styles were correctly being loaded now.

```
bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
```

Maybe this helps somebody.

Comment: This would be consistent with Paul's answer above which states that `.min` files are ignored by default. He also suggests either clearing the IgnoreList or renaming the files to remove the .min.

Comment: Thx a LOT! IgnoreList was the reason... Why?

Answer (score 2):

I don't use bundles for Bootstrap (as an exception), but its minified versions, so this works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 60px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css")">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/less")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
```

The part with the inline style is from http://www.initializr.com/ for the top NavBar, if you don't need it, just remove.

Alternatively, you can do the same in your styles.css file:

```
@import url('bootstrap.min.css');

body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

@import url('bootstrap-responsive.min.css');

You CSS Code below
```

Comment: Well that certainly works but I was hoping to use the bundles.  I really like the idea of using bundles.  Feels 'Rails like' to me.  :-)

Comment: On your update...importing it into the site.css is even better.  I will use that method unless someone can show me how to use it in the bundle.

Comment: @cbmeeks Bundle depend on debug mode, also it has ignore list.

Comment: Looks like the ignore list was it???  bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();  fixed it.  Post this as an answer and I will award it to you.  But I still don't know why that fixed it?

Comment: There's a bug in that by default when in debug mode, *.min.js will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

As paul correctly stated, bundles as set to automatically ignore 'min' files. But ignoring this rule all together is a bad practice, please refer to this answer [Bundler not including .min files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/bundler-not-including-min-files) to a better solution (check both first and second answers).