# How to catch error in bundle?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I have bundle config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.web.min.js"));
```

I have view render:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

But render only jquery. Why?
I have exist file in /Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.web.min.js path

I need catch error from bundle. How to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569259/asp-net-mvc-4-scriptbundle-returns-empty/12569908#12569908