# ASP.NET ScriptBundle does not work with .min.js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I can successfully include jquery library with ScriptBundle from ASP.NET MVC by using below

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"));
```

However, If I changed to the minimized library, I could not get it from browser

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"));
```

anything wrong with the code?

Comment: there's no need to use the min script anymore. the bundler will min it for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless `EnableOptimizations` is `true` or the debug attribute in the compilation Element  in the `Web.config` file is set to false, files will not be bundled or minified. Additionally, the `.min` version of files will not be used,  the full debug versions will be selected. `EnableOptimizations`  overrides the debug attribute in the compilation Element  in the `Web.config` file

[more info](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`

Answer (score 9):

Try clearing ignore list.

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

            // code cleared for clarity

        }
    }
```

Comment: great! Thanks, I have more options now!

Comment: Good quick fix to get back to work, but beware that some of your wildcard include patterns might pick up scripts you wouldn't want to include: see [this answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12005272/177710) for what the defaults in the `IgnoreList` are.

Answer (score 3):

Everything OK with your code, that's how it works, you can try change `ignoreList`.

More details: [mvc4 bundler not including .min files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/mvc4-bundler-not-including-min-files)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that question, it helped me figure out what this `IgnoreList` contains by default.