# MVC Bundling - Include .min file for a single bundle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-optimization

I have a single file in my application that I only have a minified version of and I would like to create a bundle for it:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/maskedinput").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"));
```

The problem is that by default in debug mode, the bundling mechanism ignores .min files. I don't want to turn off this rule for all bundles, but I would like to disable it for this single bundle. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick fix is to rename the js file taking out .min. Or as per the solution in this link you can create your own ignore patterns.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12005272/1593273

Answer (score 3):

This is also fixed in the 1.1-alpha1 release, so if you update to that version, you should no longer see this behavior when including files explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can either rename the file without the .min, or you can copy the file to have both a .min and one without.  It's just that they're now both the same.