# Bundle Wont Include

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple bundle I wish to include

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bjqs")
```

The bundle config looks like this

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bjqs").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bjqs-1.3.min.js"));
```

However it just never gets included.

If I manually include it like this

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bjqs-1.3.min.js");
```

It works, but that defeats the purpose of the bundle.

Help me stack overflow, your my only hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you may need to clear the IgnoreList,especially if you are including min files in your Bundle.

```
 bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
```

and then Add

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bjqs").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bjqs-1.3.min.js"));
```

A Good post on this behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/mvc4-bundler-not-including-min-files)

Comment: yes its sort of weird it will also include if you take out the word "min" from the file name.looks like this is been fixed as being stated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290977/mvc-bundling-include-min-file-for-a-single-bundle