# Bundling Styles doesn't work, but straight Link tag works

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, bundle

In my _Layout page, following works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.common.min.css")"             />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.blueopal.min.css")"           />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.dataviz.min.css")"            />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.dataviz.blueopal.min.css")"   />
```

This doesn't work (the styles do get applied, however images referenced in the css don't render):

> @Styles.Render("~/bundles/kendoStyle")

here's the Bundle def in App_start -> BundleConfig.cs:

> ```
>         //Kendo Styles:
>         bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/kendoStyle").Include(
>           "~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.common.min.css"
>         , "~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.blueopal.min.css"
>         , "~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.dataviz.min.css"
>         , "~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.dataviz.blueopal.min.css"
>             //, "~/Kendo/Content/contextMenu.css"
>         ));
> ```

What am I doing wrong here? (please note, "Kendo" is setup as an mvc4.5 web app under my main website

Answer (score 9):

Image paths are relative to the folder in which styesheets are located. For example, an image might be referenced like this:

```
.k-icon {
  background-image: url('BlueOpal/sprite.png');
}
```

Because your bundle redefines the path to your stylesheets, the browser attempts to download the image from *~/bundles/BlueOpal/sprite.png*, which doesn't exist. The actual path to the image is *~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/BlueOpal/sprite.png*.

Everything works fine when you link to your stylesheets directly (without the bundle) because relative paths correctly point to images on your server. However, because your bundle redefines the virtual path in which the stylsheets are located the relative paths to images no longer work.

If you want to use a bundle you must define it with a path that will not break relative image paths in the stylesheets. In your case, since the KendoUI stylesheets are located at *~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918*, you should define the bundle with that same path:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/bundle").Include(
    "~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.common.min.css",
    "~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.blueopal.min.css",
    "~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.dataviz.min.css",
    "~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.dataviz.blueopal.min.css"
));
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent explanation! however, when I do make the change, the styles completely disappear. I'm sure we're really close though. 2 reminders, one, "Kendo" is a "web app" under my main website (I don't think that should matter greatly). Secondly, through an F12 -> "network tap", I see the new bundle gets a 404-not found response. Also, when I go back to my original bundle def (where only images fail to load), using F12, I manually enter "~/Kendo/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/BlueOpal/sprite.png to get it to work (without the "/" in front of the path images fail to loat)

Comment: ok, things are getting interesting; So "Kendo" is a virtual directory / web app under my site. There's a link here that says bundle name and directory structure should be distinct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540528/bundling-scripts-are-not-getting-rendered?rq=1 I guess this is a complete show stopper in terms of adding Kendo as a web app under my site and use bundling to load it? that would be a shame really

Comment: This is absolutely a fantastic answer to resolve the issues where it renders differently, client or server side!

Comment: @Kevin Babcock Five years later, your answer is still relevant to explain why images from Kendo stylesheets fail to load when bundled. Creating the bundle in the original root folder solved my problem. Thanks a bundle!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I hat the same problem. but I saw that the page was able to get the sprite file, but does not show some symbols. The temporally solution was set the bundle EnableOptimizations property to false.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = False
```