# Javascript Bundle

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem, my bundle command doesn't include my javascript UI,

My code is below:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

I have the "jquery-ui-1.10.2.min.js" file in the script directory, however, in my browser it is not included.

Why is it, according to you ?

If have 2 files with different versions, how will the bundle will know which version to use?

Comment: Does your `{version}` include the ".min"?

Answer (score 0):

Minified files .min.js are excluded by default.
You can either rename your file to jquery-ui-1.10.2-min.js or change the exclusions.

Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/mvc4-bundler-not-including-min-files)