# jQuery DataTable won't work in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have an index.cshtml file with a simple table.  I downloaded the css file and the min js file for the dataTable plugin.  I put the following code in BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/table").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"));

 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.dataTables.css"));
        }
```

In my _Layout.cshtml, I have this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/table")
```

Finally, in my index.cshtml, I put the following code above my table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#patients').dataTable();
    });
    </script>
```

I noticed when I run the page with the table and view the source, I see the jquery file at the bottom and my script at the top, so I get the error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Is BundleConfig the correct place to add new js and css files? How do I do it if I don't want it to be there?  Why is jquery script run at the bottom of the page?

I added the following to _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/table")
```

but now I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dataTable'

When I view the source, I see the dataTables.min.js is not there, but I have included it in bundles/table.

Comment: did you call jquery.js before calling datatables?

Comment: Well, when I look at the source, my script is called before jquery, so I know why it is undefined, but I thought modernizer would run jquery before my script since it is included in the _layout.cshtml file.

Comment: Where do you include jQuery on your page?

Comment: I thought modernizer includes it, that is called in my _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: I added it to my _layout.cshtml, but now I get another error.

Comment: Are you sure `~/bundles/modernizr` bundle contains jQuery?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev - It would appear not, I added it, but I get another error now. I updated my post.

Comment: Do you have any 404 errors in console? Did you provide a valid location for your datatable.js file?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev - Jquery is loading, but the dataTables script is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default if you have Debug="True" in your web.config, minimized javascript files are not included in bundles. Add this to your BundleConfig.cs (or use a non-minified javascript file, or run in non-debug mode):

```
#if DEBUG
            //by default all minimized files are ignored in DEBUG mode. This will stop that.
            bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
#endif
```

Additional info: [Bundler not including .min files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/mvc4-bundler-not-including-min-files)

Comment: This was it. It was totally throwing me off. Thanks.

Comment: 10 months later: thanks!! Finally that headache is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Modernizer, out of the box with an asp.net MVC project, has nothing to do with jQuery.

I would update your bundles so you have one for jQuery and one for jQuery plugins, or one that does both. e.g.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jQuery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jQueryPlugins").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"));
```

If you add any additional jQuery plugins, then just register them with the jQueryPlugins bundle.

Then make sure that in your _Layout you Render the jQuery bundle first.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jQuery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jQueryPlugins")
```

This way you know you always have jQuery included before the plugins.

**Note**

Also make sure that you have your scripts rendered before your jQuery code which is on your page. e.g.

```
@Scripts.Render("...")
```

Before

```
$(document).ready(function(){ .... }
```

Comment: Tim, jQuery was already there. I added the dataTable one as ~/bundles/tables and added it to my _Layout.cshtml, but it says dataTable is not a method

Comment: Tim, I put @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/table") at the top of my page, but when viewing source, I don't see the dataTables plugin script.  Also, if it is already rendered with Layout.cshtml, why do I have to put it in my Index.cshtml page as well?

Comment: No you don't need it in your Index.cshtml. Just make sure that the code in your Index.cshtml is after the Rendering of the scripts on the _Layout page.

Comment: I put it at the top, but I don't even see the plugin loaded.

Comment: Its calling jquery and then my script. It is not loading the dataTable plugin that I put into ~/bundles/table.

Comment: The path to the file correct and exist? /Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js is your project online that we can see and inspect the scripts?