# How can I reference a *.min.css file in an MVC4 StyleBundle?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I am using Kendo UI in an MVC4 application. I've decided I want to move my CSS and JS references to bundles. I created a bundle like so:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/baseCSS").Include(
            "~/Content/CSS/Shared/Site.css",
            "~/Content/CSS/plugins/jquery.jgrowl.css",
            "~/Content/Kendo/kendo.common.min.css",
            "~/Content/Kendo/kendo.blueopal.min.css"));
```

I reference the bundle in my _Layout.cshtml like so:

```
Styles.Render("~/bundles/baseCSS")
```

The HTML of my page (in debug mode) renders only the site.css and jquery.jgrowl.css references. If I rename the kendo CSS files and remove the "min" part of their name and change the string in my bundle, it works fine. Why can't I reference a .min?

Also, I have explicitly disabled optimization in the BundleConfig.

Comment: It uses `min` as needed when you build for debugging. When you build for release it uses `min`. By putting `min` in your config it is likely looking for `min.min`. Here's a post with lots of info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/bundler-not-including-min-files

Comment: Thanks Jasen...this is exactly what I need. If you add a link as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses `min` as needed when you build for debugging. When you build for release it uses `min`. By putting `min` in your config it is likely looking for `min.min`.

Here's a post with lots of info [Bundler not including .min files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/bundler-not-including-min-files)

Comment: Indeed. That's pretty much the whole point of Bundles: you work with the unminified source broken up into as many files as you need to organize your project and Visual Studio bundles them all up into a single file for you when publishing release.

Answer (score 1):

In a bundle you can not use min because when you add a css or js file in bundle it automatically minify the file.

You can reference the file directly from your layout such as..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Kendo/kendo.common.min.css" />
```

Or you can remove the .min extension from your file name and then add to the bundle such as..

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/baseCSS").Include(
            "~/Content/CSS/Shared/Site.css",
            "~/Content/CSS/plugins/jquery.jgrowl.css",
            "~/Content/Kendo/kendo.common.css",
            "~/Content/Kendo/kendo.blueopal.css"));
```