# Does mvc 4 bundling require a number on the js file in order to use the -{version}?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, system.web.optimization

I've been struggling to get my bundle to resolve my .js files at runtime in release mode i.e. with the <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />.

After some hours I chanced changing the name of my .js files to file names with a number. This now works. 
But I cannot find any documentation on it! is there some explanation?

Here's my bundling code, the last 2 files are mine:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/topoix").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/JSON.js",
                    "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/tp-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/tpmodel-{version}.js"

             ));
```

This doesn't render the scripts when the file names are
~/Scripts/tp.js,
~/Scripts/tpmodel.js,
~/Scripts/tp.min.js,
~/Scripts/tpmodel.min.js

but does when the file names are

~/Scripts/tp-1.0.0.js,
~/Scripts/tpmodel-1.0.0.js,
~/Scripts/tp.min-1.0.0.js,
~/Scripts/tpmodel-1.0.0.min.js

(the difference being the addition of -1.0.0 to the file names).

Answer (score 0):

For defaul bundle ignore .min files, so rename the files or use the uncompressed version.

Or add bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

[Bundler not including .min files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/bundler-not-including-min-files)

Comment: Thanks but I still don't see why adding a number to my file names fixed my debug/release bundle issue. I also read the post you've pointed to but don't see any explanation from my resolution.

Comment: have you used nuget for this library?

Comment: Using the Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio 2010 to get my package into a MVC4 web app.