# MVC 5 bundles.ignoreList.Clear not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I upgraded my MVC4 to MVC5, now all my files, that were ending with `.min` or `.debug` are not included in bundle. In MVC4, `bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();` helped, but not anymore.

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {

        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();     

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/library")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Libraries", "*.js", true));
    }
```

How to make it not to ignore my `.min` and `.debug` files in MVC5?

Comment: is it `file-min.js` or `file.min.js`?

Comment: Sorry, it is file.min.js.

Comment: Just rename it :) See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/bundler-not-including-min-files/12901050#12901050)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems there is no way to include `file.min.js` to the bundle. But `file-min.js`, `file-debug.js` and `file.debug.js` still work.

See this [demo project](https://github.com/maxbrodin/mvc5-bundle-test)

**Note**: Project uses packages:

[Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/)

[Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 5.2.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/5.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed my problem was the ignore list when my script bundle stopped showing up when EnableOptimizations was on, and spent an hour trying to fix my minified filenames and such. However, my problem turned out to be the bundle names I was using, which contained a '.' in them.

For example, changing

```
new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/root1.0ThirdParty")
```

to

```
new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/root10ThirdParty")
```

fixed the issue for me, and everything worked even with minified files in the includes.