# MVC Bundling: IncludeDirectory not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to add a Scripts bundle to my MVC site. At first I explicitly named the files:

```
var scripts = new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/bundle")
    .Include("~/scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js")
    .Include("~/scripts/jquery.validate-1.13.0.min.js")
    .Include("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");

bundles.Add(scripts);
```

This works as expected. However, I then decided it would be easier to just include the whole directory:

```
var scripts = new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/bundle")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/scripts", "*.js", true);

bundles.Add(scripts);
```

This second approach does not output anything when calling `@Scripts.Render()`, so I can only assume the `IncludeDirectory` method has not found anything. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have also tried the wildcard syntax

```
var scripts = new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/bundle")
    .Include("~/scripts/*.js");
```

This also fails to render anything

Comment: Hi AlexFoxGill, I believe that this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/bundler-not-including-min-files is solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var scripts = new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/bundle")
    .Include("~/scripts/*.js")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately this did not work either. It might help someone else though