# Mvc4 datatables does not work in script bundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, bundle, bundling-and-minification

I have following code in the **App_Start/BundleConfig.cs**

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datatable").Include(
                    "~/Content/DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/site.css", 
                    "~/Content/DataTables-1.10.7/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"));
```

and in the **Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatable")
```

and CSS and Datatable just does not work, but when I add manualy

```
<link href='@Url.Content("~/Content/DataTables-1.10.7/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css")' rel="stylesheet" />

<script src='@Url.Content("~/Content/DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

it starts to work. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Rename js scripts with "min" to ones without it. Bundles have problems when including scripts with "min" in their names. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/bundler-not-including-min-files

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the source code of the web page from the browser and be sure that;

*jquery.dataTables.min.js* is loading **after** *jquery.min.js*

Change the order in your **_Layout.cshtml** as:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")    
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatable")
```

**EDIT :**

It may also be about **web.config** settings.

If you have "*Debug = True*" in your web.config, minimized javascript files are not include in bundles.

Add this to your **BundleConfig.cs** :

```
#if DEBUG
        //by default all minimized files are ignored in DEBUG mode. This will stop that.
        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
#endif
```

Comment: css, modernizr, jquery is default ordering when I create project. I only added datatable bundle after jquery as you say

Comment: @Muflix Editted my answer.