# Kendo UI Scripts are not bundling in MVC5

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC. I have bundled all the kendo JS files. Locally its working fine. But when i deployed the application to the web server and then when i browse the page i noticed the kendo javascripts are not bundled and because of that i am getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).kendoDropDownList is not a function

**This is how i am bundling the files**
[image: Bundled Files]

**This is how i am referencing them in _Layout.cshtml**

```
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap/css")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo-bootstrap/css")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css" />


        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo/2016.1.412")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
```

**This is what i see in browser's F12 -> Source Tab**

[image]

Note that jQuery,Modernizer and Bootstrap is bundled but not kendo. Why?

Comment: do the files exist on the server you are deploying the application too? It maybe that the folder and subsequent files are set to `Do not copy' for the Copy to Output Directory.

Comment: file does exists on the server

Comment: I have noticed on your include the kendo.timezones.min.js file appears to have an extra `s` at the end of it. (may be nothing but just wanted to point it out just incase that is the issue) - locally you might be using a cached version which worked previously

Comment: well removed that extra `s` however no luck :(

Comment: one more thing. I am using Jenkins + MSBuild + Publish options. So i basically i have created publish file which uses "File System" as publish method. and then i use MSBuild to build and publish the application.

Comment: There is discuss here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/bundler-not-including-min-files/12901050#12901050` about why MVC is not bundling .min files..however there is no solution for it

Answer (score 1):

so finally it started working..i have followed the telerik's article [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-5)
The only difference in that article vs what i was doing
was:

JS file location in project: Mine was `~/Scripts/kendo/2016.1.412` and suggested `~/Sripts/kendo`
CSS file location in project: Mine was `~/Content/kendo/2016.1.412` and suggested `~/Content/kendo`

Also in BundleConfig.cs file
JS Bundle Script Name: Mine was `~/bundles/kendo/2016.1.412` and suggested `~/bundles/kendo`
CSS Bundle Script Name: Mine was `~/Content/kendo-bootstrap/css` and suggested `~/Content/kendo/css`

i dont know why would this make a difference, because ultimately i was referencing to correct bundle names in layout.cshtml

but anyway above changes worked for me

Comment: You should accept this as your answer since this is how you solved the problem.