# asp.net mvc 5 - StyleBundle CdnFallbackExpression questions?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I've added bootstrap CSS files via a StyleBundle to my asp.net mvc 5 project.

(It uses as Cdn: https://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn#Bootstrap_Releases_on_the_CDN_14 )

```
  var bootstrapCssCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css";
  var bootstrapCssBundle = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/bootstrap", bootstrapCssCdnPath).Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css");
  //bootstrapCssBundle.CdnFallbackExpression // ?
  bundles.Add(bootstrapCssBundle);

  var bootstrapThemeCssCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css";
  var bootstrapThemeCssBundle = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/bootstraptheme", bootstrapThemeCssCdnPath).Include("~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css");
  //bootstrapCssBundle.CdnFallbackExpression // ?
  bundles.Add(bootstrapThemeCssBundle);
```

However there is a problem: when I add an incorrect url as CDN (e.g. adding 'ahttp' instead of 'http') my custom "fallback" css file is not used, instead it shows 'ahttp://' in my html source.
Same when I'm running my site on Debug or Release.

1. Why is my fallback not being used?
2. What is the CdnFallbackExpression for a StyleBundle? (and in particular for a bootstrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css)
3. Should the .Include be the .min.css file or does it automatically search for the .min. version first?
4. Is there a way to .Include multiple css files, using a Cdn with fallback, so that I don't have to create a new StyleBundle everytime per css file that uses a Cdn?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1)** This is a bug in the Microsoft ASP.NET Optimization Framework, documented [here](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/104).

**2)** The solution is to modify the `CdnFallbackExpression` to be a javascript function that both checks for the stylesheet and loads the fallback, thus ignoring the bad script from the Optimization Framework.

Here is solution which provides a `StyleBundle` extension method to solve the problem: [Style Bundle Fallback](https://github.com/EmberConsultingGroup/StyleBundleFallback).

**3)** There should be unminified version like `bootstrap.css` (not `bootstrap.min.css`). When you build your web application for release it uses `.min` version. More here: [Bundler not including .min files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/bundler-not-including-min-files).

**4)** No, you can't use multiple CSS files with CDN (each of them must have its own bundle). Here is an article that explains when to use a CDN (or not) and why: [Know When To CDN](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/know-when-to-cdn).