# Bundle JS files using CDN and integrity attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bundle, cdn

In ASP.NET MVC 5, is it possible to use `BundleColletion.UseCdn` and have it render with the HTML integrity attribute? For example, is there someway to make this:

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;
bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js")
        .Include("~/Scripts/js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js")
);
```

render as this?

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @Ben Cook, I am also facing the same issue. Any solution for this?

Comment: @VigneshVS the best solution is the top-rated answer, but as noted, it's not a great solution. I don't think there is a clean way to do what I wanted in ASP.NET MVC 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partial answer.

To add crossorigin="anonymous" attribute you can use ***@Scripts.RenderFormat***

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>", "~/bundles/jquery")
```

You also can  include *integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="* part in RenderFormat, but it does not look like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this way in our ASP.NET MVC 5 project when CDN fails

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' integrity='sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>", "~/bundles/bootstrapJS")
```

And this will generate (inside developer tool),

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652660/asp-net-mvc-5-stylebundle-cdnfallbackexpression-questions) answer we found that there is bug if script is fail to load from CDN

So we add script manually inside the  tag.

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>(window.jQuery) || document.write('<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"><\/script>');</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have it like

```
 <script src='@Scripts.Url("~/bundles/jquery")' crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="value"> </script>
```