# Why SignalR is not loaded properly when my ASP.NET MVC application is published on IIS using bundle optimization?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, signalr

It seems that when running my application using SignalR on my development server with IIS I get the error below in the JS console (while it's completely fine running the application locally in Debug):

> ```
> Uncaught Error: SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.
> at hubs:17
> at hubs:106
> ```

Line 17 is related to:

```
if (typeof ($.signalR) !== "function") {
    throw new Error("SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.");
}
```

Line 106 is just the end of the IIFE.

Here is below BundleConfig class:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        var scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/bundle");

        // jQuery
        scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js");

        // Bootstrap
        scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js");

        // Knockout
        scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js");

        // SignalR
        scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-{version}.js");

        // Custom site scripts
        scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/scripts.js");
        scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/scripts-bootstrap.js");
        scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/scripts-devextreme.js");


        var styleBundle = new StyleBundle("~/Content/bundle");

        // Bootstrap
        styleBundle.Include("~/Content/bootstrap-telus-theme.min.css");

        // Font Awesome
        styleBundle.Include("~/Content/font-awesome.min.css");

        // Custom site styles
        styleBundle.Include("~/Content/Site.css");
        styleBundle.Include("~/Content/Site-bootstrap-plus.css");
        styleBundle.Include("~/Content/Site-devextreme-plus.css");


        bundles.Add(scriptBundle);
        bundles.Add(styleBundle);

        #if !DEBUG
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        #endif
    }
}
```

The doctype on the development server looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="favicon" href="/Content/favicons/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="favicon" sizes="32x32" href="/Content/favicons/favicon-32.png" />
    <link rel="favicon" sizes="128x128" href="/Content/favicons/favicon-128.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/Content/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/Content/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/Content/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/Content/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144.png" />

    <link href="/Content/bundle?v=KoFrSDNrdsCobjey_0WoDyRHewQDRrB1Ov9eEHg15EI1" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/DevExtremeBundle?v=dvjWkuzRNPhpuO8epzd1bapDA4VbH3NGrM9XfK6lfH41" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/bundle?v=bk8qAjn5FOZNS6DjmQ8qRN1l5sZzYFEHYS7tNOnf4vk1"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/DevExtremeBundle?v=EDbcZoJEzBcOEMDXw50S76TV4vRJy8nCjafsccwoAas1"></script>

    <script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

In local debug (so without the bundle optimization):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="favicon" href="/Content/favicons/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="favicon" sizes="32x32" href="/Content/favicons/favicon-32.png" />
    <link rel="favicon" sizes="128x128" href="/Content/favicons/favicon-128.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/Content/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/Content/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/Content/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/Content/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144.png" />

    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-telus-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Site-bootstrap-plus.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Site-devextreme-plus.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/dx.common.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/dx.telus.light.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.debug.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/scripts-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/scripts-devextreme.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/cldr/unresolved.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/message.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/currency.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/date.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/dx.all.debug.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/aspnet/dx.aspnet.data.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/aspnet/dx.aspnet.mvc.js"></script>

    <script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

What is published on the development server does not run with a DEBUG constant, how can I make it work without it? 
Imho the `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` line is not supposed to mess up my signalR bundling and still that's pretty much the only difference I can see between the two. However when running with the development server configuration locally it also works even with the optimization bundle enabled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happened because bundle optimization is skipping min files. And you bundled JS doesn't have jQuery, which is required for SignalR.

For more details, please check this answer: [Bundler not including .min files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980458/bundler-not-including-min-files)

Comment: you mean that because it does not consider the minified versions like scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"); jquery is omitted.